# use of url in django

Tags: python, django, url

I have a doubt in use of `urls` and `path` in `urls.py`.
I have tried a url in django as:

`url('budget-info/<str:username>',views.app_view, name='app')` along with:

`return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('app', kwargs={'username':user.username}))` and

`return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('app', args=(user.username,)))`

in my `views.py`. I am getting error of this type:

`Reverse for 'app' with keyword arguments '{'username': 'admin'}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['budget-info/<str:username>']`

However this is working fine with `path` in replace of `url`. I cannot understand why this is happening considering that both `url` and `path` are used to design url.

Comment: `url` and `path` are not the same. `path` **replaces** `url` in Django 2.x. If you use `url` you must use regex patters and Django won't understand `<str:username>` (it just interprets it as part of your url). But `url` is deprecated so you shouldn't use it at all. So just use `path` and `re_path` everywhere and you'll be fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you read [this documentation on the URL dispatcher](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/http/urls/), nowhere `url` is mentioned. So please follow the docs and use `path` or `re_path` only.

`url` is deprecated. You can find it in books and tutorials that were made for Django versions 1.11 and earlier. It works differently than `path` (it's actually equivalent to `re_path`) as it **always** requires a regular expression to match variables.